# JQuery how to get nested id inside onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

```
<button class="button" onclick="$('#4').popover('show')">Click me</button>
```

I have some code like above code snippet. I just need an id to pass into the onclick event.

The actual id I want to use is this button sibling's id, which I could get through

```
$(this).prev().attr('id')
```

I want to know how to replace #4 with #$(this).prev().attr('id'). Any thoughts?

Comment: Do it in a handle function

Comment: @passion can you shed some more lights?

Comment: First of all, use `jQuery.on` to register click/any events... In current code, you can try `$(this).prev().popover('show')`

Comment: Atleast write that id 4 html in question

Comment: @Rayon Got it!!! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Rayon! I got the answer - super straightforward!

`$(this).prev().popover('show')`

Answer (score -3):

You can try with .parent()
Something like this:

```
$(this).parent('#parentId')
```

...if it's parent, or they are on the same level?

Of course, you can write some script where you can create variable for this parent id so you can write:

```
var parentID = $(this).parent('#parentId');
```

then you can write:

```
$(parentID).popover('show')
```

For siblings you can use:

```
$(this).siblings( "#siblingId" )
```

Comment: IT's a sibling, not a parent.